# Get Updates on Favorited Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not sure if this is a Stackexchange thing or a WP Meta question exactly but I was wondering why, whenever you favorite (click the star) on a question, you don't get alerts / notifications whenever the question has been updated or answered? Can we add that as a feature?

By "alerts / notifications" I'm referring to your inbox section, in the top bar next to the Stack Exchange logo. Usually when somebody answers or comments on one of your questions or a question you've commented on you get a tick in your inbox saying there has been an update. It labels it as either a comment or answer. Could we add this functionality to questions you favorite?

Answer (score 1):

There are updates, but they are on your profile page:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/123456/your-user-name?tab=favorites
```

which in your case would be [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7355/howdy-mcgee?tab=favorites).

Comment: Right, but why wouldn't they appear in your inbox? That's what I consider the notification center. Top bar, next to the StackExchange logo.

Comment: I answered your question because it took me some time to figure that one out myself. I'm not completely happy with the current situation, especially because I really don´t know anything about my fav stack. But on the other hand, I´d be quite annoyed if I constantly get notifications on any change that I subscribed too - consider typo fixes such a thing. The main reason I don´t use facebook is the constant *Y U NO PARTICIPATE!!1!* calls such overly "social" apps throw at me. In other words: I´m somehow glad that it´s  the way it is.

Comment: True, but you currently don't get updates on edits to questions you've answered or questions you've commented on (at least not to my knowledge). Only on *Your* questions. I would still like to get notifications on favorited questions whenever an answer is added.

Comment: You should add a new feature request that´s more about general notifications on questions where you participated and reference this one.